# the system cannot find the drive specified - Windows Service

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-services

I've this batch file who]ich does exactly what I want to. I developed a windows service where I call the .bat file and I install it to run as windows service.

This is the content of the batch file:

```
copy temp\cambio.csv X:\
copy temp\cambio.csv V:\
copy Y:\Cambios.pdf X:\
timeout 600
```

When I run using windows service the output is:

```
E:\SERVICES PACKAGE\Cambio>copy temp\cambio.csv X:\ 
    1 file(s) copied.
E:\SERVICES PACKAGE\Cambio>copy temp\cambio.csv V:\ 
    1 file(s) copied.
E:\SERVICES PACKAGE\Cambio>copy Y:\Cambios.pdf X:\ 
 The system cannot find the drive specified.
```

The Drive Y:\ is a drive that I mapped from other server and it seems that the windows service is trying to access it through **E:\SERVICES PACKAGE\Cambio>** (which is the dir where the .bat file is).

The question is: How do I fix that? 
Instead of the windows service be locking in the dir where the .bat file is search all mapped drives.

Comment: Is using UNC paths an option? Bear in mind that drive mappings are a per-user setting that can always be changed, it seems dangerous to rely on them if they can be avoided. I view them mostly as a legacy thing. Also, is there a reason why your service cannot directly perform these actions itself, rather than calling the batch file?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Well, I'm new in the company and I figure out that they've more that 50 batch files running here. And if the server restart some reason, someone have to access them and start all batch files manually. That's why I decided to write a service master which only call the batch file instead of reworking all services and putting them as win-services.

Comment: They are a per token mapping. So the account that the batch file is in has to have the mapping. If the account can elevate the mapping is to the state that was mapped, eg mapping a drive and then running notepad elevated, notepad can't see that mapping.